# Which 2 sentences are correct?

Tags: grammaticality, commas

> Blockquote

Can't wait to celebrate, my bags are packed.

Sorry to miss it, can't find my passport.

> Blockquote

Can't wait to celebrate. My bags are packed.

Sorry to miss it. Cant find my passport.